# my computed values stopped working with latest version of ember-data.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am getting the following error when i change attributes of a model.

```
Uncaught Error: <DS.StateManager:ember466> could not respond to event setProperty in state rootState.loading.
```

Here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/arenoir/JejwD/ http://jsfiddle.net/arenoir/JejwD/show

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since revision 6 of ember-data (see [breaking changes](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md)), IDs are string-normalized. As a result, you'll need to update your fixtures to use strings for IDs (note: the REST adapter will convert numbers/strings, but the fixture adapter doesn't do any conversions).

Making the following changes to your fixtures seems to get your example working:

```
App.Address.FIXTURES = [
    {id: '1', streetnumber: '1018', streetname: '4th Ave', city: 'Oakland', state: 'Ca'} 
];

App.Job.FIXTURES = [
    {id: '1', address_id: '1', customer_id: '1', name: 'bathroom addition', rate: "310", hours: "1000"}
];

App.Customer.FIXTURES = [
    {id: '1', firstname: 'Mike', lastname: 'Smith', jobs: ['1']}
];
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/dgeb/GVU7n/

Comment: This was a tough solution for me to find. I'm new to Ember, but should this be documented somewhere more plainly?

Comment: I agree. I'm afraid that the docs for ember-data are far behind those for ember itself.

Comment: Yes the docs are not very good. If anyone is interested, these are the issues I had to deal with to get Ember Data fixtures to work for me in general (with nested models): http://www.vinay.io/static/blog/2013/12_17.html