# failed to get embedded's object property using ember.js with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to ember, and try to understand how it works.

I've defined a store with a fixturesAdapter as adapter (rev 7).
I've defined two models:

```
App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    item: DS.belongsTo('App.Item')
});
```

and:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    tags: DS.hasMany(App.Tag, { embedded:true }),
})
```

I also fill their associated fixtures and at last a controller:

```
App.itemsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: App.store.findAll(App.Item)
});
```

I've defined a function inside App.Item model:

```
tagline: function(){
    return this.get('tags').toArray().map(function(tag){
        return tag.get('name');
    }).join(',');
}.property('tags.@each.isLoaded')
```

Here is the corresponding jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K286Q/29/

My questions are:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Why does it see several tags associated to first item, but is not able to get their name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running up against a few breaking changes in the current version of ember-data.

The first is that, since revision 6 of ember-data, IDs are string-normalized and must be represented as strings in fixtures. Note that the REST adapter will convert numbers/strings, but the fixture adapter doesn't do any conversions. This is a common source of confusion (see [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296022/my-computed-values-stopped-working-with-latest-version-of-ember-data-js)).

The second is that support for embedded data objects has been temporarily removed from ember-data. I'm pretty sure that this feature will be re-introduced in a better way than supporting `{embedded: true}` in the attributes. IMO, embedding is more of an adapter concern and doesn't really belong with the definition of the model.

I adjusted your fixtures and got your example working here: http://jsfiddle.net/dgeb/zHz4Y/

Comment: Thanks for detailled and clear explanations as well as the updated example

Comment: Helpful! The lack of (full?) id-to-string coersion in fixtures just bit me in rev 11 as well. Good to know!