# EmberJS Binding Content Between Controllers

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, binding, ember.js

I'm currently working with two data models, where Foo has a "toMany" property of type Bars.  I'm now trying to create two select boxes where when the first populated with Foo's is picked, it refines the second listing only the Bars associated with that foo.

JSFiddle Here:  http://jsfiddle.net/drew/6jLCy/

Code below, but it certainly doesn't work. It does go as far as setting the SelectBox values for the first, but doesn't populate the second with the corresponding bar value titles.

```
App = Em.Application.create();

App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 7,
  adapter: DS.fixtureAdapter
});

/**************************
* Models
**************************/

App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
    bars: DS.hasMany('App.Bar'),
    title: DS.attr('string')
});
App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
    foos: DS.hasMany('App.Foo'),
    title: DS.attr('string')
});


/**************************
* Fixtures
**************************/

App.Foo.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Footitle 1',
        bars: [0,1]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Footitle 2',
        bars: [0,1,2]
    }
];

App.Bar.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Bartitle 1',

    },{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Bartitle 2'
    },{
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bartitle 3'
    }
];


/**************************
* Views
**************************/

App.SetFooField = Em.Select.extend({
    contentBinding: 'App.fooController',
    valueBinding: 'content.selected',
    optionLabelPath: 'content.title'
});

App.SetBarField = Em.Select.extend({
    contentBinding: 'App.barController',
    valueBinding: 'content.selected',
    optionLabelPath: 'content.title'
});

/**************************
* Controllers
**************************/

App.fooController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: App.store.findAll(App.Foo)
});

App.barController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    contentBinding: 'App.fooController.selected.bars'
});​
```

Markup for the html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">

    {{view App.SetFooField}}
    {{view App.SetBarField}}

</script>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

holy cow. after many days of going nearly nuts, it turns out this is entirely a bug in the latest ember-data.  in fixtures, all ids need to be strings. just. plain. nuts.

```
/**************************
* Fixtures
**************************/

App.Foo.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: '0',
        title: 'Footitle 1',
        bars: ['0','1']
    },
    {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Footitle 2',
        bars: ['0','1','2']
    }
];

App.Bar.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: '0',
        title: 'Bartitle 1',

    },{
        id: '1',
        title: 'Bartitle 2'
    },{
        id: '2',
        title: 'Bartitle 3'
    }
];
```

[failed to get embedded's object property using ember.js with ember-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296812/failed-to-get-embeddeds-object-property-using-ember-js-with-ember-data)

huge thanks to @dgeb for answering that question.

jsfiddle updated accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/drew/6jLCy/